Python callback on local cache TTL expiry
I am looking at utilizing a caching solution to store reference to a memory mapped file. I have a use case where every time stored reference TTLs I need to make sure I close the reference explicitly [Do not want to rely on GC to do it].
If I use aiocache, cachetools, functools or any other caching library, is there a method to specify call back method for TTL expiry? or can I override expiry method to write a wrapper over the cache? Hoping there should be a way with the existing libraries without having to implement complete cache logic with TTL expiry.
One solution I can think of is wrapper for the memory map reference with override __del and this ensures everytime the object is garbage collected I can close in del method, however this relies on GC call cleaning up the object.
Any suggestions are appreciated.
